# Handling BizTalk dynamic WCF-WebHttp ports suspended messages

Tags: dynamic, http-status-code-404, port, biztalk

I am creating a Biztalk dynamic port WCF-WebHttp.

When I get a response back in the form of a HTTP 404, the port suspends the following error is shown

> System.Net.WebException: There was no endpoint listening at https://test.xxx.com/xxxx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   {"type":"availability.not_found","message":"No availability was found for the properties requested."}

I have tried to add an exception handler to the BizTalk orchestration. It handles the error but I still see a suspended instance.

I wish to handle the 404 error and to stop the port from suspending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Transport Advance Options on your Send Port Properties, switch on Enable routing for failed messages.
Have something subscribing to the Error Report from that send port, e.g. we use a custom Null Adapter with the rule `ErrorReport.SendPortName == NameOfSendPort`

[image]

Comment: Hmmm that is very interesting...... I implemented this and it works like a charm. Question what is causing the error? Does wcf-webhttp always suspend on 404 responses? or is it my custom pipeline that is throwing this error?

Comment: I used the null adaptor http://www.integrationsoftware.se/products/biztalk-adapters/null-adapter-for-biztalk/

Comment: There are some issues with the way the WCF-WebHttp adapter handles errors.  Including not setting the HttpResonseCode in the Context Properties nor putting the correct namespace on the "SOAP" error message it creates.  In fact for doing Restful stuff, you wish you could suppress throwing an error on a 404 as that is a Not Found message really.  Did a presentation on it http://www.integrationusergroup.com/what-is-right-wrong-WCF-WebHTTP-Adapter/

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you have to setup around this for it to work 'as expected'.

This article: [BizTalk Server: Suspend and Resume an Orchestration on Two Way Port Error](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31665.biztalk-server-suspend-and-resume-an-orchestration-on-two-way-port-error.aspx?Sort=MostRecent&PageIndex=1)

...describes how to setup the Orchestration, the Port and handling the failure notifications.